# Parse iOS SDK: saveEventually and logout

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm writing an app using Parse which saves data to the server over a connection with unknown stability. As such I'm using saveEventually.

I'm trying to deal with the situation where the app is minimised, and then terminated by the system before a save is complete. The trouble is, when
opening the app afresh, I issue a logout command, since users are required to log in. It appears that this logout command can overtake the save commands, removing the session from the server, causing the queued save commands to fail. (I also can't see any way of handling these failures after an app restart, since I don't see any delegate based handlers, and blocks are cleared.)

I can't see any user-facing solutions to this either, since there is no guarantee when saveEventually might decide to run, and I can't block the user indefinitely.

Has anybody dealt with this? Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Are you performing a logout because using anonymous users ?

Comment: No it's because the audience is young school kids and teachers; there's a pretty good chance any protocol for use (like always log out) isn't always going to be followed.